# how to close viewpager images in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am developing an app in which I am using a ViewPager to slide images in an Activity.
There is a sign up screen on that Activity.
When I sign up, the Activity opens and the images can slide (for that I use a ViewPager).
It also contains a button at the top, so that when I want to close it, it closes and the sign up page will be brought to front.

I have done this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                viewPager.cancelLongPress();
            }    
        });
    }
}
```

My layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/view_pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
      </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
          android:background="#000"
          android:text="close"
          android:textColor="#FFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is just to set INVISIBLE to this viewpager.

```
yourViewPager.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE)
```

You also can set VIEW.GONE as well. It will make the viewpager does not occupy any space.

Comment: Chris, I want to set button on pictures so that when images slides button will also with the pictures. I want to put it on view pager but how?

Comment: Actually what you set into viewpager are not images but fragments, right? So just put buttons into fragment's layouts accordingly.

Comment: Its just a single activity and in layout i set View Pager which slides the image. i am not using any fragment. Images are in Adapter class. Can i show u that?

Comment: Yes, u are using ImageAdapter, so u only can add images into it. However if u want to add button into each page, u'd better use [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) or its subclass FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Wrap your image and button as either a layout in fragment or a custom view. Here is an example http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html . Hope  I am clear.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce `SparseArray<Fragment>` in your adapter and add item in this array in your `getItem` overload `destroyItem` and use it in your adapter and you will get a callback in `destroyItem` for each item on close button click.